# Using ISFORMULA with reference to a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table to enumerate the headers in another table, and I want it to show whether a column is calculated or not. I've used `ISFORMULA` to look it up, which works fine as long as I stick to the same worksheet, but I can't seem to find a way to reference a cell on another sheet. I'm currently using this:

```
=IF(ISFORMULA(ADDRESS(2, $D2, 1, 1, "BMSB Finds")), 1, 0)
```

The other worksheet is called "`BMSB Finds`", the column number is held in column D. This just leads Excel to tell me that the formula contains an error.

I've also tried using an index match, which presents no errors but also just shows FALSE regardless of the cell content.

Using manual references works, of course, but means going cell by cell, thus ruining the point of doing it automatically.

Any idea how to make `ISFORMULA` accept the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ADDRESS` returns a text (textual representation of an address), while `ISFORMULA` requires an address, that's why Excel is giving you can error.

You should be able to use `INDEX`:

```
=IF(ISFORMULA(INDEX('BMSB Finds'!1:10000,2,$D2)),1,0)
```

Adjust the range as necessary.